# Why $\int_m \left( y^2 + z^2 \right)dm \neq \frac{1}{3}mL^2$?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, integration, moment-of-inertia

for a cylinder, let's say with constant density with radius $3$ and height $10$ so

$$
\rho(r, \theta, y)=1
$$

so
$$
dm = \rho\left(r, \theta, y\right)r \, dr \, d\theta \, dy = r \, dr \, d\theta \, dy
$$

in that case the inertia at the end of the rod is ([from here](http://formulasheet.com/db/engineering/mechanical_engineering/dynamics/inertia_tensor))

$$
I_{xx} = \int_m \left( y^2 + z^2 \right) \, dm=10060.91
$$

where $z = rsin(\theta)$

but ([from here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/imgmec/mic.png))

$$
\frac{1}{3}mL^2 = 9424.77
$$

but

$$
I_{xx} = \int_m \left( y^2 + z \right) \, dm=9424.77
$$

if $z=sin(\theta)$

why is this?

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates, $z$ should be a direct variable, and the only angle should be azimuthal, so that $x=\rho \cos(\alpha)$ and $y=\rho \sin(\alpha)$.

Comment: A typesetting details here is that you want the differentials to be identifiable as distinct entities. So you set them off with a thin space (`dr\, d\theta` to get $dr\, d\theta$). I'm one of the people who also like to typeset the "d" upright (so `\mathrm{d}r` to get $\mathrm{d}r$), but that is much less universal.

Comment: @FGSUZ in my case $y$ is the direct variable and $x, z$ are not. As in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259247/non-uniform-density-rod-center-of-mass/3259312#3259312.

Comment: Oh, could you then draw the axes and the limits of integration? Thanks. By the way, I think there's a missing squaring in your last formula

Comment: @FGSUZ on purpose because it works

Comment: The $1/3 ML^2$ is for the rod about it's end?

Comment: @Aaron Stevens yes it is

Comment: So how does it have a radius?

Comment: Don't you want the equation for the cylinder in your link? (Bottom left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you are doing the integral
$$\int_0^{10}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3\left(y^2+r^2\sin^2\theta\right)r\,\text dr\,\text d\theta\,\text d y$$

So you are assuming your cylinder is oriented along the y-axis, and $\theta=0$ lines up with the positive x-axis. The value $y^2+z^2$ is the distance a point is from the x-axis. Therefore, based on your limits of integration your cylinder's base is in the x-z plane, and you are calculating the moment of inertia about the x-axis.

Looking at your link then, you want to use the equation in the lower left corner along with the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem), not $I=1/3ML^2$ for the thin rod. More explicitly:
$$I_{xx}=\frac14MR^2+\frac1{12}ML^2+M\left(\frac12L\right)^2=\frac14MR^2+\frac13ML^2$$

This is the equation you want for your moment of inertia. Plug in your numbers and it all works out.

Why does your integral with the $z$ instead of $z^2$ work out to be $1/3ML^2$ like the rod on one end? Well if you don't square $z$ in the integrand, then this term integrates to $0$ due to the $\sin\theta$ term from $0$ to $2\pi$. Therefore the integral is equivalent to just integrating over $y^2$. This would be the same as if you were looking at a rod for $R=0$. This is why you get $1/3ML^2$ for your incorrect integral

Comment: no you don't understand, the problem is that the integration gives another value that the equation for a special case. i need the integration to give me the same answer. i do not care about the special case equation, i am just using it for verification. also it is not the equation in the lower left for the origin is not in the middle.

Comment: here is how the cylinder looks like https://imgur.com/V70wTa9

Comment: @fullnitrous Yes I deduced that figure from the integral. My answer is what you want. Please read it more carefully.

Comment: but the equation in the bottom left has the rotation axis in the center which i do not.

Comment: @fullnitrous Which is why you use that with the parallel axis theorem. As stated in my answer.

Comment: oh sorry I read your and the equation in the image as the same. also just a quick question. if I would want the rotation axis to be around the center of mass $(C_x, C_y, C_z)$ would I just subtract $C_x$, $C_y$ ect. from $x$, $y$ and $z$ when integrating?

Comment: @fullnitrous Do you mean have the axis of rotation still parallel to the x-axis but through the center? If so, then you just change your y limits to be from $-5$ to $5$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96876/discussion-between-fullnitrous-and-aaron-stevens).